# Why does the svg spec differentiate between unsettable and readonly attributes?

Tags: svg

[Section 4.5.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#InterfaceSVGElement) of the SVG 1.1 spec (version 2) describes the SVGElement interface--the 'base class' of SVG objects. It says:

```
interface SVGElement : Element {
           attribute DOMString id setraises(DOMException);
           attribute DOMString xmlbase setraises(DOMException);
  readonly attribute SVGSVGElement ownerSVGElement;
  readonly attribute SVGElement viewportElement;
};
```

Attributes:

- id (DOMString)

  - The value of the ‘id’ attribute on the given element, or the empty string if ‘id’ is not present.
    Exceptions on setting

    - `DOMException`, code `NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR`
          Raised on an attempt to change the value of a read only attribute.
- xmlbase (DOMString)

  - Corresponds to attribute ‘xml:base’ on the given element.

    Exceptions on setting

    - `DOMException`, code `NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR`
          Raised on an attempt to change the value of a read only attribute.
- ownerSVGElement (readonly SVGSVGElement)

  The nearest ancestor ‘svg’ element. Null if the given element is the outermost svg element.
- viewportElement (readonly SVGElement)

  The element which established the current viewport. Often, the nearest ancestor ‘svg’ element. Null if the given element is the outermost svg element.

So none of these attributes are writeable. Why do two of them raise exceptions if you try to write to them? Do the other two not raise exceptions? What is the difference between 'readonly' and 'setraises'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setraises` doesn't mean that the attribute isn't writeable. It just means that setting it *may* raise a DomException.  In the SVG DOM, all attributes that are not `readonly` are annotated this way.

In the case of SVGElement.id, I am not aware of any situation in which setting `id` will throw an exception.  Perhaps, in some SVG implementations, there are rare situations in which the DOM is in a state where it doesn't allow `id` to be changed.  But I don't think you need to worry about that.

As far as `readonly` attributes go.  It is up to the implementation whether it simply ignores attempts to set it, or throws an exception.

Comment: Note also that `readonly` only affects the attribute itself, not things that are inside it. You can e.g do `someSVGElement.ownerSVGElement.currentScale = 2;`